# How do I make changes to my local db in asp.net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first

I am using VS2013 and .net framework 4.5. I was following [this getting started tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-search) when halfway down the page I noticed that there was a Ratings column that was not part of the original build and also was not explained as far as how to include the missing column into the local database and update the model. In the comments the author admits to the issue and says that he will update it, however the tutorial is 2 years old.

So, I did some digging on the matter and according to [this solution](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/changing-the-database) I should make a change and simply click <kbd>F5</kbd> but this does not work. 
I even added the ratings object to the model class.

Instead of changes being saved to the project Visual Studio wants to save the changes as a separate SQL file. Should I not expect the changes to be saved to the movies.mdf? How is this done?

Comment: The tutorial you're following is code first. The solution you've found is data first. Look here instead: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/01/tips-when-making-changes-in-entity-framework-code-first-models-after-scaffolding.aspx

Comment: @BenJaspers I was able to get the package manager running and used `Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName MVCMovie.Models.ApplicationDbContext` to try to update my local db. Once I completed that I typed Add Migration as the tutorial suggested. When I look at the database in the server explorer it still does not show  that the column has been added.

Comment: You have to run Update-Database after Add-Migration to update the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Entity Framework **Code-First** according to my understanding and links you shared.

There is no need to handle the database with queries. All you need to do is "Play with the Code in Class".

Dont forget to [Enable Migration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx) to project file.

After that whenever you change the code and update your model class. Go to the **Package-Manager Console** and apply "**add-migration migrationName**" to the selected project and then apply another command "`update-database`".

This will update the database.